# UIActivityViewController in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app I have added these lines of code to incorporate the functionality of uiactivityviewcontroller

```
    UIImage *yourImage = someImg;
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abcdefgh",yourImage, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeMessage ,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and UIActivityViewContoller working fine, but the UI is like this: no FB icon, no Twitter icon and this is a screen-shot of an iPad:

[image: screenshot of an iPad]

However it is showing perfect UI in iOS 6. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on iPad mini + iOS7 + iPhone app. It works fine on iPhone 5. My guess is that this has something to do with the fact that now all iPhone-only apps are forced to run in 2x mode.

Comment: the problem is with device.. When i tested in my ipad it shows that error but when i tested in iphone it worked fine.. and mine was an iphone app

Comment: nope... Though i have faced this long back, as far as i can remember this design was for iPhone and we tried to make it run on iPad.  You please try run it on iPhone hope it will work completely fine.

Answer (score 4):

Let me tell you that your code is correct, after some test finally I could fix it, just go to Settings add Social Accounts (Facebook - Twitter - Flickr - Mail), run again your app and you will see the icons. Regards from Cancun!
[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue although I added accounts in setting app.
Here is same issue ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619418/on-ios7-ipad-1x-2x-mode-facebook-twitter-icon-only-missing-in-uiactivityviewco

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the Simulator? In my experience, `UIActivityViewController` the UI is buggy in the simulator, but if you test on an actual device, it runs fine.

Try testing on a device.

Comment: No i'm checking it in a device , this is a screen shot of a device

Answer (score 3):

the problem was with the device.. It was running well in iPhones